How to integrate Tiptap Rich Text Editor with ShadCN UI and Next.js?
I'm working on a Next.js project using ShadCN UI for my form components. I want to replace a simple  field with a Tiptap rich text editor for the description field in my form.
Here is the current code for my form field:
<FormField
  control={form.control}
  name="description"
  render={({ field }) => (
    <FormItem className="mt-6 flex lg:space-x-12 max-lg:space-y-6 lg:flex-row flex-col sm:max-w-5xl max-w-xl justify-between">
      <div className="w-[284px] mt-3">
        <FormLabel className="font-semibold">Description</FormLabel>
      </div>
      <div className="space-y-6 flex-1">
        <FormControl>
          <Input {...field} placeholder="Description" />
        </FormControl>
        <FormMessage />
      </div>
    </FormItem>
  )}
/>


I have installed Tiptap and its necessary extensions:
npm install @tiptap/core @tiptap/react @tiptap/starter-kit @tiptap/extension-link @tiptap/extension-placeholder 
How can I replace the  field with a Tiptap editor,

you must create your own component and customize it. Here's an example on github:https://github.com/DevendraBhoraniya/text_editor

There is a minimal setup for this minimal tiptap. and there is an example too on how to use it with react-hook-form
